# When calling FFI C functions from LLVM code, when is an `sret` return pointer necessary?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, llvm, ffi, calling-convention

It appears that C functions which return structs sometimes use a [magic hidden return argument](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-March/097690.html) carrying a pointer to some memory to be overwritten with the return value of the function.

For example, a C function declared like:

```
MyBuffer string_from_double(double d);
```

will appear in LLVM like:

```
declare void @string_from_double(%struct.MyBuffer* sret align 8, double)
```

Despite appearances, the function actually has two arguments instead of one. The magic argument is apparently identified by its [`sret` tag](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#parameter-attributes).

(Bewilderingly, LLVM doesn't automatically perform the transformation from return-by-value, even for `cdecl` convention functions. There must be a reason for it, but it seems counterintuitive to me).

So my question is: From the compiler backend, how do I tell when an FFI function needs to be transformed into an "sret" form?

Comment: This will depend on the ABI for the target platform, and varies wildly from platform to platform. For X86 platforms, see the survey in Table 7 of https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf

Comment: @rici It seems like this makes LLVM a leaky abstraction— I thought LLVM IR is generally supposed to be architecture-agnostic. Is there a way to get LLVM to tell me what I should do? E.g., is [`Type.isSingleValueType()`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Type.html#a5f6edc5246188225b3f49bd5c974c759) a reliable way to check? How do other systems which implement FFI generally solve it?

Comment: What compiler backend are you talking about in your question?

Comment: @arrowd, the one I'm writing, which I'd like to make able to  invoke FFI functions.

Comment: How do you inform your frontend about FFI calls? Are you parsing C headers for this?

Comment: @arrowd That's not *exactly* what I'm doing, but function and type declarations are basically the information that I have access to, so it's probably safe to imagine that I am.

Comment: Well, then you have to replay what Clang does in case of C function returning a struct. Or in other words, what C standard say on this matter.